# Float precision breakdown in python/numpy when adding numbers

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have some problems due to really low numbers used with numpy. It took me several weeks to trace back my constant problems with numerical integration to the fact, that when I add up floats in a function the float64 precision gets lost. Performing the mathematically identic calculation with a product instead of a sum leads to values that are alright.

Here is a code sample and a plot of the results:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import vectorize, arange
import math

def func_product(x):
    return math.exp(-x)/(1+math.exp(x))

def func_sum(x):
    return math.exp(-x)-1/(1+math.exp(x))

#mathematically, both functions are the same

vecfunc_sum = vectorize(func_sum)
vecfunc_product = vectorize(func_product)

x = arange(0.,300.,1.)
y_sum = vecfunc_sum(x)
y_product = vecfunc_product(x)

plot(x,y_sum,    'k.-', label='sum')
plot(x,y_product,'r--',label='product')

yscale('symlog', linthreshy=1E-256)
legend(loc='lower right')
show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the summed values that are quite low are scattered around zero or are exactly zero while the multiplicated values are fine...

Please, could someone help/explain? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If `np.float64` is not enough, there is `np.float128`. Does it have the same problems?

Comment: Yep, same problem for float96...

Comment: Why not do these sums in the log domain to avoid the precision problem?  http://lingpipe-blog.com/2012/02/16/howprevent-overflow-underflow-logistic-regression/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point precision is pretty sensitive to addition/subtraction due to roundoff error.  Eventually, `1+exp(x)` gets so big that adding 1 to exp(x) gives the same thing as exp(x).  In double precision that's somewhere around `exp(x) == 1e16`:

```
>>> (1e16 + 1) == (1e16)
True
>>> (1e15 + 1) == (1e15)
False
```

Note that `math.log(1e16)` is approximately 37 -- Which is roughly where things go crazy on your plot.

You can have the same problem, but on different scales:

```
>>> (1e-16 + 1.) == (1.)
True
>>> (1e-15 + 1.) == (1.)
False
```

For a vast majority of the points in your regime, your `func_product` is actually calculating:

```
exp(-x)/exp(x) == exp(-2*x)
```

Which is why your graph has a nice slope of -2.

Taking it to the other extreme, you're other version is calculating (at least approximately):

```
exp(-x) - 1./exp(x)
```

which is approximately

```
exp(-x) - exp(-x)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of [catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Let's look at the first point where the calculation goes awry, when `x = 36.0`

```
In [42]: np.exp(-x)
Out[42]: 2.3195228302435691e-16

In [43]: - 1/(1+np.exp(x))
Out[43]: -2.3195228302435691e-16

In [44]: np.exp(-x) - 1/(1+np.exp(x))
Out[44]: 0.0
```

The calculation using `func_product` does not subtract nearly equal numbers, so it avoids the catastrophic cancellation.

---

By the way, if you change `math.exp` to `np.exp`, you can get rid of `np.vectorize` (which is slow):

```
def func_product(x):
    return np.exp(-x)/(1+np.exp(x))

def func_sum(x):
    return np.exp(-x)-1/(1+np.exp(x))

y_sum = func_sum_sum(x)
y_product = func_product_product(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `func_sum` is [numerically unstable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability) because it involves a subtraction between two very close values.

In the calculation of `func_sum(200)`, for example, `math.exp(-200)` and `1/(1+math.exp(200))` have the same value, because adding `1` to `math.exp(200)` has no effect, since it is outside the precision of 64-bit floating point:

```
math.exp(200).hex()
0x1.73f60ea79f5b9p+288

(math.exp(200) + 1).hex()
0x1.73f60ea79f5b9p+288

(1/(math.exp(200) + 1)).hex()
0x1.6061812054cfap-289

math.exp(-200).hex()
0x1.6061812054cfap-289
```

This explains why `func_sum(200)` gives zero, but what about the points that lie off the x axis? These are also caused by floating point imprecision; it occasionally happens that `math.exp(-x)` is not equal to `1/math.exp(x)`; ideally, `math.exp(x)` is the closest floating-point value to `e^x`, and `1/math.exp(x)` is the closest floating-point value to the reciprocal of the floating-point number calculated by `math.exp(x)`, not necessarily to `e^-x`.  Indeed, `math.exp(-100)` and `1/(1+math.exp(100))` are very close and in fact only differ in the last unit:

```
math.exp(-100).hex()
0x1.a8c1f14e2af5dp-145

(1/math.exp(100)).hex()
0x1.a8c1f14e2af5cp-145

(1/(1+math.exp(100))).hex()
0x1.a8c1f14e2af5cp-145

func_sum(100).hex()
0x1.0000000000000p-197
```

So what you have actually calculated is the difference, if any, between `math.exp(-x)` and `1/math.exp(x)`.  You can trace the line of the function `math.pow(2, -52) * math.exp(-x)` to see that it passes through the positive values of `func_sum` (recall that 52 is the size of the significand in 64-bit floating point).